# CONCAT date issue

Tags: php, mysql, date

My database has y m d fields with no leading zeros in the month and day. I am trying to compare a records y-m-d against today's date. Greater than or equal show a greenlight image else red light. It's not working! HELP!

```
    $q = "SELECT * FROM pec_mbbtmssgs WHERE activity='bike' AND CONCAT(`y`,'-','m','-','d')  >= date('Y-n-j')";
$r = mysql_query($q);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
$activity = $row['activity'];

if($activity == "bike") {
    $image = "greenlight25";
}
else {
    $image = "redlight25";
}

echo '<img src=http://img/' . $image . '.gif />';
?>
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly: Do you have separate columns for `y`, `m` and `d`?

Comment: Besides, look at the quoting here `CONCAT(\`y\` ,'-', 'm', '-', 'd')`, you're using backtick for `y`, but singlequotes (so it's interpeted as strings) for `m` and `d`.

Comment: yes, separate columns of y, m and d

Comment: tried changing all the quoting to either backticks or single quotes and it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your usage of `CONCAT()` is a bit off, as database-columns should either be wrapped in backticks or nothing at all, and strings/separators in singlequotes `'`.

You can also just do `DATE(NOW())` to get the current date, and compare against this. Then you use the `DATE()` with the result of your `CONCAT()`, so it becomes like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM pec_mbbtmssgs 
WHERE activity='bike' 
  AND DATE(CONCAT(y, '-', m, '-', d)) >= DATE(NOW())
```

The simpler approach would be to just store your date in a `DATE` type column, instead of 3 separate ones. You can always extract the specific information you want (e.g. you can extract the month, even if your value is `2016-11-30`).

Comment: Yippee! that works! The only question I have is since the date for today in both my database, and the DATENow function all have 2 numbers for the month and day. When the month turns to January will it still work OK or does Date(NOW() return a value with a leading zero for single digit months or days?

Comment: That should work. You can verify that by running something like `SELECT DATE('2016-01-01') = DATE('2016-1-1')`, which should return true (`1` in MySQL) - so it wouldn't matter if there is a leading zero or not, as long as the format is correct. Happy to have helped though! If this answer solved your issue, please [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) :-)

Comment: Like I said though, it's probably easier to deal with 1 `DATE` column (`yyyy-mm-dd`) rather than 3 separate integers columns. If you ever just need the month, you can do `SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2016-11-30', '%M') as month`, which would give you `11`. You can replace `2016-11-30` with the name of a `DATE` type column.

Comment: Thanks. I agree the 1 Date column would make more sense but the calendaring software I am using inserts the y d m into 3 different fields in the database. Way beyond my current skills to try to change it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM pec_mbbtmssgs WHERE activity='bike' AND unix_timestamp(CONCAT(`y`,'-',`m`,'-',`d`))  >= unix_timestamp(CURDATE())";
```

Comment: Tried this one and it didn't work. I guess what I am trying to do is build a string with my y m and d fields and compare it to the current date which I believe is also formatted as a string. Thus comparing one string to another.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your comment but did you used CURDATE()? Please execute following SQL. It might get you some idea. The comparison should work.  select unix_timestamp(CONCAT(2016,'-',11,'-',30)), unix_timestamp(CURDATE())

Comment: plugged it in just as you sent, but still not working. The y, m, d, fields in the database are just numbers, not in unixtimstamp. I am trying to get them in a yyy-m-d format to compare them to date('Y-n-j') which is in the same format with no leading zeros on the n and j numbers. Trying to compare apples to apples but not working.

Comment: Ive run both  date("Y-n-j") and then CONCAT(y,'-',m,'-',d), separately, and they both return dates in the YYYY, n j format. I just can't get them to compare to each other in the query and produce the desired result.